# graph theory problem on computer communication

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Can someone please help me to do this problem:
There are 1958 computers which can communicate among themselves in six languages with the condition that any two computers can communication with only one language out of 6 languages.Prove that there are at least three computers whose mutual language of communication is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix one of the computers. It communicates to $1957$ other computers in six possible languages, so it will communicate to $\lceil \frac{1957}{6} \rceil = 327$ computers in the same language. If any pair of those $327$ computers communicate in that language, we are done. Otherwise, we have reduced the problem from six to five languages.

Comment: Is it like this. Suppose any pair of those 327 computers do not communicate in that language. Consider the 327 computers select one out of them.Then this selected computer can communicate with the other 326 in 5 languages.So it will communicate with 66 computers in same language. If any pair of those 66 computers communicate in that language, we are done. Otherwise, we have reduced the problem from five to four languages.Continuing in this way $\lceil \frac{65}{4} \rceil = 17$,$\lceil \frac{16}{3} \rceil = 6$,$\lceil \frac{5}{2} \rceil = 3$.

Comment: @Artur The final 3 is left with only one language to communicate,hence we have found at least one three pair who communicates in a mutual language.Is this the way this should be done?

Comment: Yes, that's it.